# Transferring large files with web services

Tags: web-services, soap

What is the best way to transfer large files with web services ? Presently we are using the straight forward option to transfer the binary data by converting the binary data into base 64 format and embeding the base 64 encoding into soap envelop itself.But it slows down the application performance considerably.Please suggest something for performance improvement.

Comment: What platform are you using? .NET? Java? PHP?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out **MTOM**, a W3C standard designed to transfer binary files through SOAP.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MTOM):

> MTOM provides a way to send the binary
>   data in its original binary form,
>   avoiding any increase in size due to
>   encoding it in text.

**Related resources:**

- [SOAP Message Transmission Optimization Mechanism](http://www.w3.org/TR/soap12-mtom/)
- [Message Transmission Optimization Mechanism (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MTOM)

Comment: I am having problem of sending file contents by soap - SoapFault Request Entity too large - any idea mate???? please help

Answer (score 12):

In my opinion the best way to do this is to not do this!

The Idea of Webservices is not designed to transfer large files. You should really transfer an url to the file and let the receiver of the message pull the file itsself.

IMHO that would be a better way to do this then encoding and sending it.

Comment: What if you have to make available, to an external system, a web service which allows to send email with relative attachments? I think there is no way to by pass the usage of web-service, is there a way?

Comment: You cannot make simple statements like that without knowing the OP's project requirements or any other person's requirements that are reading this, for that matter,   A real-time request and response will not work with your suggestion.

Comment: The OP explicitly stated "Please suggest something for performance improvement" so the quality goal is clear here. A real-time request response was no quality goal in the question of the OP. So for me the answer is still valid, if you need performance for the web service request, postpone the file transfer.